# Regenerate location pop up even after it's denied - Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation

Using JavaScript, is it possible to clear location preferences stored in the browser so that even if I've denied the location permission once, the pop up can be regenerated.
Alternatively, if the above cannot be achieved then can I generate a link that allows a user to navigate to the location settings option?

Comment: It is explicitly implemented this way, to stop sites annoying the user by asking over and over and over again. (So asking this makes about as much sense as the classic, “how do I circumvent the popup blocker?” - you _don’t_, because if you could, it would mean the blocker was defective.) And there is no “the” location settings option - every browser handles their settings differently.

Comment: @CBroe Right, makes sense.